# Returned value for $.when.apply($, $.map(array, someFunction(x){}))?

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

What is returned from getTickets function?

```
function getTickets(needsTickets) {
    return $.when.apply($, $.map(needsTickets, function(x) {
        return function(x) { return $.ajax() } ;
    }));
}
```

Comment: a promise is returned. `getTickets('someValue').then(function(){ alert('All ajax is done');})`

Comment: actually would be more like `getTickets(someArray).then...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's analyze what is happening:

The result of `$.when` is a promise and that is what is being returned.

`$.when` doesn't accept an array as arguments so to handle an array of promises you need to do:

```
$.when.apply( context, promiseArray);
```

The promise array is being created by `$.map`

Answer (score 0):

`$.when` returns a [promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)

It can be use to attach aysnchronous callback. They'll be executed at the end of the `$.when` execution.

```
$.when(...).done(function() {
    console.log('everything is ok');
}).fail(function() {
    console.log('not ok');
}).always(function() {
    console.log('always called');
});
```

`apply` is a javascript built-in function on functions. It can be used to call a function with an array for arguments. This 2 lines does the same thing :

```
myFunction.call(null, ['test', 'test 2']);
myFunction('test', 'test 2');
```